# How to make sure that no word is repeated in a csv file using php?

Tags: php, csv

I have a .csv file like this

**file.csv**

> green,yellow,blue,white

these values will change dynamically during runtime but stays in the same format in the single first line in the file.csv.

During runtime sometimes it comes like this

> green,blue,violet,violet,blue

that means some of these values are repeating and that should not have happened in the file.

Is there anyway which will prevent the word repetition using php.?

what I have done so far is given below which seems to be wrong

```
First I took the file into an array , $color
$array=array();
foreach($color as $col1)
   {
      foreach($color as $col2)
      {
         if(strcmp($col1,$col2)!=0)
         {
            $array=$col1;
         }
      }
   }
file_put_contents('file.csv',$array);
```

I know this doesn't have any logic, but this is what i could do as a pioneer .

Comment: Would exploding and filtering, be an option? (array_unique)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: Do you just want to drop duplicates from the first line (field names), or are there data columns below those that also have to be dropped?

Comment: @CBroe yes want to drop duplicates from the line and i guess the function array_unique can solve my issue!!

Comment: once in a while the above mentioned file becomes like this green,blue,,yellow . two commas are coming together can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be

```
$file = 'file.csv';
file_put_contents($file, join(',', array_unique(explode(',', file_get_contents($file)))));
```

Comment: Excellent!! two line saves too much of processing!!                  +1 on the day when I earns required reputaion

Comment: I have one more question,,,  once in a while , the above mentioned file becomes like this      green,blue,,yellow     . 2 commas are coming together can I avoid that?

Comment: That's because you have empty values, I think. Use `array_filter()` to remove them

Comment: array_filter( $array, 'strlen' );               will this do? or should i change the callback function?

Comment: upvoted as I promised ( got 15+ reputation)   thnk u

Answer (score 1):

```
$array=array();
foreach($color as $col1) {
    $array[] = $col1;
}
file_put_contents('file.csv',array_unique($array));
```

Comment: Not only that, I think. also remove those useless cycles :p